# OAUTH token login using hostname

Tags: oauth-2.0

My application is setup using OAuth authentication.

When I login to my application from my server using localhost or IP address it works fine, and I am able to get the OAuth token and able to login successfully.

But, when I access my application externally using hostname it fails to get the token causing unable to login to my application.

Is there a way that I can resolve my hostname to IP address or is there anything i need to add to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? If you provide some portion of code, you can get a faster and more useful answer.

Comment: For ex: If i use my IP 10.10.10.1 or localhost inside my server I can login successfully
whereas if I use my hostname externally I cannot because the OAuth token is generating based on my IP and not my hostname